# mpmath slower than decimal in simple multiplication

Tags: python, time-complexity, precision, mpmath, python-decimal

I am wondering why mpmath is so much slower than decimal when doing the same operation for the same precision settings.

```
from decimal import *
from mpmath import *
import timeit
from decimal import Decimal as dc
from mpmath import mpf
import sys

# Set the same precision 
getcontext().prec = 15
mp.dps = 15

# A random function which does multiplication using mpmath
def mpf_test():
    a = mpf('2202020202002020.21212')
    b = mpf('3202020202002020.21212')
    c = mpf(0)
    for _ in range(10000):
        c += (a*b) / (a*b)

# The same function which does the multiplication using decimal
def decimal_test():
    a = dc('2202020202002020.21212')
    b = dc('3202020202002020.21212')
    c = dc(0.0)
    for _ in range(10000):
        c += (a*b) / (a*b)


# Print results
print(F"Using Decimal: {timeit.timeit(stmt=decimal_test, number=100)}")
print(F"Using mpmath: {timeit.timeit(stmt=mpf_test, number=100)}")

# Check if gmpy2 is used in mpmath
if 'gmpy2' in sys.modules:
    print(F"You are using gmpy2")
```

Output:

```
Using Decimal: 0.3805640869977651
Using mpmath: 2.961118871004146
You are using gmpy2
```

The difference is around a factor of 8..

I am using Python3.8, my machine is a new T14s with AMD7 and 32 GB RAM (Dont know if it makes any difference.. )

Comment: Is your `mpf_test()` correct?

Comment: @JonSG oops. Sorry, I made a mistake while simplifying the problem.. now i have the corrected function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpmath` is written in Python. `decimal` is written in C. C extensions have less interpreter overhead. That's about it.

Note that even if you have gmpy2 installed, that just means `mpmath` will use gmpy2 integers instead of regular Python ints under the hood. It won't automatically C-accelerate the whole `mpmath` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to add that I similar testing was done using gmpy2.mpfr --  (which Is C-accelerated) and the results were comparable to decimal. In fact for the same test as above, gmpy2.mpfr was slightly faster at  3.3 seconds.